# Avoid exponential notation and string

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, exponential

I would like to convert `8.8e-7` to the number `0.00000088`, and not a string version of `"0.00000088"`.

So far I've tried:

```
number.toFixed(8) // it returns a string "0.00000088"
BigNumber(number).toNumber() // it returns a number 8.8e-7
```

I need that value in `Number` because I'm using that data in a graph, and it doesn't take Strings.

Any idea how to force convert it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why? It's just a notation when the data is displayed. Why can't you just convert it to a nice string later? Store the number, and format it as you want when you display it.

Comment: It's not meant for display, it's for data processing of a big array of Numbers.

Comment: 8.8e-7 and 0.00000088 are both equivalent and the only difference is their representation - as numbers they are exactly the same -  a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value. If you want to display them you have to work with string to make them different

Comment: Then should I call this a bug from the graph plugin that it doesn't accept exponential?

Comment: @karimhossenbux But if you're just processing the data, why do you care how it looks when it's displayed? Again, why can't you just format it after the data is processed?

Comment: Are they coming as strings and you want to convert them to numbers?

Comment: The graph plugin should take numbers. Don't give it strings.

Comment: @mdatsev yes, getting data as string from API. But plugin doesn't care about exponential (even if type Number) or string values.

Comment: @Barmar but the exponential value that I have is a number right?

Comment: I don't know, where did it come from? Show your code

Comment: it is. console.log(number, typeof number)
// 8.8e-7 number

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert a string containing a number in exponential notation to a number(javascript Number type) you can use the `Number` constructor.

```
var number = Number("8.8e-7")
```

Then you can use `number` for calculations or pass it to functions that take numbers.

Comment: Even doing so the processing is not working. I think it's a bug from the plugin, I'm using g2.

Comment: Then the problem is not in the converting. You will have to show us more code.

Comment: If you say that 8.8e-7 and 0.00000088 are both equivalent in a Number type, then issue is from the plugin. I'm just trying to convert something impossible I guess. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a problem that I needed to avoid exponential notation.

```
const avoidNotation = (numIn: string) => {
  if (!numIn) return '';
  if (numIn === 'NaN' || numIn === 'undefined') return numIn;
  numIn += ''; // To cater to numric entries
  let sign = ''; // To remember the number sign
  numIn.charAt(0) === '-' && ((numIn = numIn.substring(1)), (sign = '-')); // remove - sign & remember it
  let str = numIn.split(/[eE]/g); // Split numeric string at e or E
  if (str.length < 2) return sign + numIn; // Not an Exponent Number? Exit with orginal Num back
  const power = Number(str[1]); // Get Exponent (Power) (could be + or -)

  const deciSp = (1.1).toLocaleString().substring(1, 2); // Get Deciaml Separator
  str = str[0].split(deciSp); // Split the Base Number into LH and RH at the decimal point
  let baseRH = str[1] || '', // RH Base part. Make sure we have a RH fraction else ""
    baseLH = str[0]; // LH base part.

  if (power >= 0) {
    // ------- Positive Exponents (Process the RH Base Part)
    if (power > baseRH.length) baseRH += '0'.repeat(power - baseRH.length); // Pad with "0" at RH
    baseRH = baseRH.slice(0, power) + deciSp + baseRH.slice(power); // Insert decSep at the correct place into RH base
    if (baseRH.charAt(baseRH.length - 1) === deciSp)
      baseRH = baseRH.slice(0, -1); // If decSep at RH end? => remove it
  } else {
    // ------- Negative exponents (Process the LH Base Part)
    const num = Math.abs(power) - baseLH.length; // Delta necessary 0's
    if (num > 0) baseLH = '0'.repeat(num) + baseLH; // Pad with "0" at LH
    baseLH = baseLH.slice(0, power) + deciSp + baseLH.slice(power); // Insert "." at the correct place into LH base
    if (baseLH.charAt(0) === deciSp) baseLH = '0' + baseLH; // If decSep at LH most? => add "0"
  }
  // Rremove leading and trailing 0's and Return the long number (with sign)
  return sign + (baseLH + baseRH).replace(/^0*(\d+|\d+\.\d+?)\.?0*$/, '$1');
};
```

It worked for me.